# By default, which web server comes in django?

Tags: python, django, webserver

In django, which web server used to host website by default?
i.e. if we host django powered website locally, at that time which web server is running in django?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django uses their own web server, which is **not** supposed to be used in a production setting.

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver

Comment: Is there any specific name of that web server?

Comment: Is it secure to use host from Apache?

Comment: I don't think there is a public name for their web server, since they do not promote the use of it. Using Apache is perfectly fine, but you are free to use other web servers as well. I personally used nginx and gunicorn.

Comment: Yes, you can use Apache it is secure, but a combination of nginx and gunicorn is easiest and compatible.